# ABPersonViewController in modally presented UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

The practical solution of my problem is to present a UINavigationController modally that has a UINavigationBar at the top containing a title and a left bar button with the title @"Done" that will dismiss the modal UINavigationController.

For whatever reason, I cannot figure out how to successfully implement this. I understand this is not the traditional use for a UINavigationController and i'm sure it's a simple solution but I cannot figure it out.

What I have tried is this:

```
ABPersonViewController *personVC = [ABPersonViewController personControllerWithCard:card];

personVC.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(ClosePeoplePicker)];

testerVCF = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:personVC];

[self presentViewController:testerVCF animated:TRUE completion:^
{
    NSLog(@"Completed");
}];
```

When I execute this code, a UINavigationController is presented but with no title and with no Done button.

Might you have a suggestion? I just don't think i'm thinking in line with how a UINavigationContoller operates.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're setting the navigation controller's barButton items, and title in the wrong place.  What you should do instead is

- configure the barButton items in the personVC's viewWillAppear method (You can access the navigationController in any view controller by accessing UIViewController's navigationController property) ie.  [self.navigationController setBarButtonItem:myBarButtonItem];
- implement the dismissPersonVC method inside of the PersonVC Class

Comment: personVC isn't a subclass of UINavigationController. how will it recognize configuration of the barButton items?

Comment: Look at my edit.  personVC has a property called navigationController which will allow you to access the nearest navigation controller above your view controller in the stack.

Comment: I want this to work, but i'm getting the same problem. Can you post some code? ps an ABPersonViewController is a cocoa class that i've built a category for. I haven't decided to override it's viewWillAppear because apple has discouraged subclassing ABPersonViewController

Comment: As of iOS 10, subclassing ABPersonViewController doesn't work - you get an all-black view. I tried swizzling `-viewWillAppear:` and `-viewDidAppear:` in order to add a Cancel button. However, the button is still removed again when Edit mode is entered and cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

If your main view controller is UIViewController than you should read that:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6

Especially that part:

```
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content
{
   [self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1
   content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController]; // 2
   [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
 }

- (void) hideContentController: (UIViewController*) content
{
   [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];  // 1
   [content.view removeFromSuperview];            // 2
   [content removeFromParentViewController];      // 3
}
```

Comment: would you please share what part of that page pertains to my question?